# Read value from an array of multiple objects (JSON)

Tags: python, arrays, json, object

I'am new to coding and try to build an HTTP-API with python. I have an Array of Objects in JSON format. I want to read a value of one of these objects.

In my python script I append a database table to an array of objects. I am looking for a solution to select a single value in one of these objects.

I have a function:

```
cur.execute(<SELECT STATEMENT>)
row_headers=[x[0] for x in cur.description]
response = cur.fetchall()
json_data=[]
for result in response:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result))) 
return jsonify(json_data)
```

the return looks like:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 123,
        "CODE": 4117,
        "STATUS": "off",
    },
    {
        "ID": 345,
        "CODE": 5776,
        "STATUS": "on",
    }
]
```

I am looking for a function(inputID):

```
where ID = inputID
set currentcode = <CODE>
set currentstatus = <STATUS>
<Do something with currentcode and currentstatus>
```

Comment: Please be more specifuc about what you mean by "I am looking for a function(inputID):"? Is there some part of doing that you understand?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this:

```py
def return_with_id(input_id):
    for x in json_data:
        if x['ID'] == input_id:
            return x
```

This will loop over every index in `json_data` and checks to see if the ID of that index is equal to what you asked for, if it finds something that matches, it'll return that and the function completes.

If you want to do other things with this, you can do so by just editing the code the code before it returns.

Comment: I tried your code in the first step without the condition (to make it simpler and prevent errors): for x in json_data: return x
I get an error: TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, since you define json_data as a list (``json_data=[]``), it must be iterable.

Comment: when I return(json_data) it returns:
[
    {
        "ID": 123,
        "CODE": 4117,
        "STATUS": "on"
    }
]

Did I understand that right that this is an array of objects? So [] is the array and {} ist the first object?
return(json_data[0]) gives the error
TypeError: 'Response' object does not support indexing

Comment: Yes, the ``[]`` is an array of dictionaries, (which are the things that encapsulated by ``{}``), hence my confusion for why you are getting an Iteration Error for the array, since those are iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error. I do not exactly know what happend with:

```
return jsonify(json_data)
```

But it seems, that this makes my array not usable/iterable. I tried it with

```
return(json_data)
```

The output looks the same but know I can use

```
for x in json_data:
```